# How to shift UITableViewCell Delete button few pixel left

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to show the delete button a few pixel left in my table view cell.
In my current implementation the delete button is touching the cell.
Please see the attached image.

But I have no idea how to do this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the built-in Delete button, your best bet is to examine the view structure of the `UITableViewCell` to find out the Delete button subview. One way to do that is to recursively enumerate all the subviews of the cell, dumping out their positions, and find the one that is located on the right most.

But that is a nasty way to do it, and the structure might change along with iOS version (especially with the upcoming iOS 7). The safer way (which requires more effort) is to create your own delete button, either with an image, or using gradient.